# Issue with Mass Transit publishing from EF Core database interceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, rabbitmq, domain-driven-design, masstransit

I have a large project following the clean architecture solution layout and some of the domain driven design / CQRS approaches.  I have followed Milan Jovanovic's early clean architecture Youtube videos quite religiously to arrive here if that helps.  Prior to integrating Mass Transit, I was using his outbox pattern approach which uses an EF core interceptor to intercept the SavingChangesAsync method, extract the events raised by the domain during that transaction and save them to an outbox table like so :

```
public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData,
    InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var context = eventData.Context;

    if (context is null)
        return base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);

    var events = context.ChangeTracker
        .Entries<AggregateRoot>()
        .Select(a => a.Entity)
        .Where(e => e.GetDomainEvents() is not null)
        .SelectMany(e =>
        {
            var domainEvents = e.GetDomainEvents();

            e.ClearDomainEvents();

            return domainEvents;
        });

    var messages = events
        .Where(e => e is not null)
        .Select(e => new OutboxMessage()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            OccurredOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Type = e.GetType().Name,
            Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            })
        })
        .ToList();

    context.Set<OutboxMessage>().AddRange(messages);

    return base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
}
```

These entries are then later picked up by a Quartz job which runs every X seconds and publishes the events using MediatR's notifications.  I will not go into greater details on this current approach simply because it works absolutely flawlessly.

I decided to replace this great approach with Mass Transit / RabbitMQ to make it a true pub/sub and get rid of the 10 second delay amongst other things.  Here is how I register Mass Transit :

```
private static void ConfigureMessageQueue(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.Configure<MessageBrokerSettings>(configuration.GetSection("MessageBroker"));

    services.AddSingleton(sp =>
        sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MessageBrokerSettings>>().Value);

    services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
    {
        busConfigurator.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

        busConfigurator.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<ISomeApplicationMarker>();

        busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
        {
            var settings = context.GetRequiredService<MessageBrokerSettings>();

            configurator.Host(new Uri(settings.Host), h =>
            {
                h.Username(settings.Username);
                h.Password(settings.Password);
            });

            configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
    });

    services.AddTransient<IEventBus, EventBus>();
}
```

The event bus is simply an abstraction of the IBus interface to decouple my application code from Mass Transit / RabbitMQ as much as possible :

```
internal sealed class EventBus : IEventBus
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;

private readonly ILogger<EventBus> _logger;

public EventBus(IBus bus, ILogger<EventBus> logger)
{
    _bus = bus;
    _logger = logger;
}

public async Task PublishAsync<TMessage>(TMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    where TMessage : class, IDomainEvent
{
    _logger.LogDebug("Publishing event {@Event}", message);

    await _bus.Publish(message, cancellationToken);
}
}
```

I will not show my consumers for brevity but they are just IConsumer implementations of the right event type.

I have made a new Ef Core interceptor that does almost the same thing except it uses the event bus to publish the event to RabbitMQ instead of saving it in the outbox table.

Here's where this gets weird.

If I publish an event directly from a MediatR handler (therefore skipping the new interceptor completely), everything works.  The message goes to RabbitMQ and hits my consumer back and does what I want.

If I try to use my interceptor, the execution does go into it at the right time, I see the event bus' logging statement that the event has been published, I see the message hitting RabbitMQ but it NEVER triggers the consumer!  As far as I can tell everything about the broker is configured correctly since it works when doing a direct call to Publish from a MediatR handler.  I see Mass Transit's logging statements that the endpoints have been configured and wired to the right consumer when the application starts up, RabbitMQ shows the exchanges and queues correctly, everything is the same (obviously since nothing at all changes compared to it working when called from a MediatR handler).

Sorry this is a lot to process but this one truly makes no sense to me.  I am happy to provide more code if it can help.  Thanks

******EDIT******

Here is my interceptor as requested.  I have tried overriding SavingChangesAsync and SavedChangesAsync with no success :

```
    public sealed class ConvertDomainEventsToMessageBrokerMessagesInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    private readonly IEventBus _eventBus;

public ConvertDomainEventsToMessageBrokerMessagesInterceptor(IEventBus eventBus) => _eventBus = eventBus;

/*public async override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var context = eventData.Context;

    if (context is null)
        return await base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);

    var events = context.ChangeTracker
        .Entries<AggregateRoot>()
        .Select(a => a.Entity)
        .Where(e => e.GetDomainEvents() is not null)
        .SelectMany(e =>
        {
            var domainEvents = e.GetDomainEvents();

            e.ClearDomainEvents();

            return domainEvents;
        });

    var res = await base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);

    foreach (var domainEvent in events)
        await _eventBus.PublishAsync(domainEvent, cancellationToken);

    return res;
}*/

public override async ValueTask<int> SavedChangesAsync(SaveChangesCompletedEventData eventData, int result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var context = eventData.Context;

    if (context is null)
        return await base.SavedChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);

    var events = context.ChangeTracker
        .Entries<AggregateRoot>()
        .Select(a => a.Entity)
        .Where(e => e.GetDomainEvents() is not null)
        .SelectMany(e =>
        {
            var domainEvents = e.GetDomainEvents();

            e.ClearDomainEvents();

            return domainEvents;
        });

    foreach(var domainEvent in events)
        await _eventBus.PublishAsync(domainEvent, cancellationToken);

    return await base.SavedChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
}
}
```

Comment: If "direct" call works and the one from interceptor doesn't, then logically the problem should be inside interceptor which you haven't shown. Could you include it in the post? I know you said "it does almost the same thing...", but the reason for unexpected behaviors usually lives in small details. For instance, forgetting to `await` some async call etc.

Comment: Added as requested.  I would absolutely agree with you if I wasn't seeing the message go through RabbitMQ .  Given this is the only thing that changes between a working state and non-working state you'd think the issue could only be there but since the message hits the queue doesn't that kinda rule it out?  This makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, no unawaited code. But still some differences with the original. Not sure what the problem is, but some things to try. First, try performing the operation in the same override (`Saving` instead of `Saved`). It's because you are querying change tracker and it might have different state inside these two. Second, for the same reason, try adding `.ToList();` at the end of the `var events = ...." to make sure these objects (or enumerable) do not change during the processing. And third, just in case, add `.ConfigureAwait(false);` to all `await`s inside the interceptor code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my issue, there is another difference between the direct publishing from the MediatR handlers and the publishing from an EF Core interceptor : one publishes concrete types and the other publishes abstract types!

All my events inherit from IDomainEvent and the list in my AggregateRoot class is a list of IDomainEvents.  When publishing directly from a handler, I can explicitly publish a concrete SomeActionHappenedEvent type, which Mass Transit/RabbitMQ recognizes.

My interceptor accessing the list of IDomainEvent types ends up publishing as an IDomainEvent, not the concrete type.  I tried publishing an explicit SomeActionHappenedEvent from the interceptor and it works just fine.

My problem ultimately was that I was using `Publish<TMessage>(TMessage message)` instead of `Publish(object message)` which was publishing things as the IDomainEvent type which Mass Transit/RabbitMQ know nothing about.  Once I switched my method signature everything started to work.

Answer (score 1):

MassTransit has its own transactional outbox that should be used instead of your custom implementation used for Mediat**R**. There is a [sample available](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Outbox) and accompanying video.

Comment: Hi Chris.  Thanks for your quick reply!  The thing is, I ultimately don't want a transactional outbox anymore.  The events are raised by the domain layer purely and the EF Core interceptor is needed in order to extract them and publish them as my domain layer doesn't have any dependencies on any other part of the application nor on any library and I want to keep it pure.  I want said event publication to be directly to rabbitMQ and picked up right away instead of using the old outbox approach.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi Chris.  I tried your outbox implementation and now the message never hits RabbitMQ despite my EventBus logging the fact that it's publishing.  Nothing is ever written to any of the 3 tables either.  Wondering if you ever tested publishing from an EF Core interceptor before?  I was thinking this might be an issue with service scopes so I tried changing my EventBus from using IBus to IPublishEndpoint and messing with singleton/scoped lifetimes with no success.  Like I said, everything works if I call my event bus' Publish method from a MediatR handler but fails when using the interceptor

Comment: I also tried publishing the events from an overriden SaveChangesAsync method directly in my DBContext (which is scoped and can use IPublishEndpoint) and I get the exact save behavior.  The message hits RabbitMQ but the consumer is never triggered.  The only way I have seen this work so far is by calling IPublishEndpoint directly from a MediatR handler which I want to avoid at all costs.

Comment: I also just found a very important detail : messages sent from my interceptor or my DBContext show as unroutable in RabbitMQ, the ones sent from the MediatR handlers show a different color and trigger publisher confirm and consumer ACK.  The only difference between these 2 mechanisms is where the publishing occurs and it uses the exact same service to do so.